# iOS13: Is there a way to disable the new swipe to type feature?

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, core-text, ios13, uitextinput

I have an app that implements a custom text view by using the `UITextInput`, `UIKeyInput` and `UITextInputTraits` protocols.

If you've installed iOS13, you've seen that the keyboard has a snazzy new feature that lets you swipe across the keys to type.

I'm wanting to disable this feature for now and I was wondering, has anyone found a way yet? I've looked around in the docs for the aforementioned protocols and haven't been able to find anything. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think imposible. Because it is system config. User manual go setting and disable it. My app will can’t change the setting

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to disable the prompt if you want to run UI tests if you add this key to your `Info.plist`:

```
Key: KeyboardContinuousPathEnabled 
Type: Boolean
Value: NO
```

Or just copy and paste this into the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeyboardContinuousPathEnabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Enabling this option will disable the simulator from showing the 'Slide to type' prompt but doesn't disable the feature - this is not possible as an OS-wide preference.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: One correction, actually the plist file should be located into the respective simulator folder, not the project's Info.plist, eg `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{SIMULATOR_UUID}/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboard.ContinuousPath.plist`